# using grep in ubuntu

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to search pattern in a file named test by using grep in ubuntu

The following is content of test

```
./foldera/[hello]this.mp4 
./foldera/folderb/[hello]that.mp4 
./folderc/[these]hello.mp4
```

On this website [regexp simulator](https://regex101.com), I use the following pattern to search and it works, three lines got matched.

```
.*\/[A-Za-z0-9\[\]]+\.mp4
```

But in ubuntu, I ran the following command in terminal, it doesn't work, nothing has returned in the terminal.

```
timothy@ubuntu:~$ cat ~/Desktop/test
./foldera/[hello]this.mp4 
./foldera/folderb/[hello]that.mp4 
./folderc/[these]hello.mp4 
timothy@ubuntu:~$ cat ~/Desktop/test | grep -E '.*\/[A-Za-z0-9\[\]]+\.mp4'
timothy@ubuntu:~$
```

What is the reasons that grep cannot search all the lines in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` extended regular expressions doesn't use backslash to escape square brackets inside square brackets. The proper way to do it is to put `]` as the first character in the square brackets; this is treated as a literal character because you can't have an empty character set.

```
grep -E '/[]A-Za-z0-9[]+\.mp4' test.txt
```

There's also no need for `.*` at the beginning. `grep` simply checks whether anything on the line matches the pattern, so adding a match for anything at the beginning or end is redundant (it's only necessary if you're using `-o` to print just the part of the line that matches).

Comment: Does any expressions allow to use backslash to escape square brackets in side square brackets? Thanks

Comment: @LeeTimothy Yes, it's used in most regexp engines based on PCRE.